# Jupyter is not able to read xlsx file and showing -Value Error : Min 0

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, readfile, valueerror

I am trying to read xlsx file but I am not able to read xlsx file from Jupyter notebook. It is showing min value 0 error. Although if, I run same code in my friend computer in Jupyter with same file it reads. It shows xlsx file is not corrupted but somehow it is not opening in my computer. Can anybody explain why value error min 0 is coming? what exactly does it mean. How can I read any file in my computer?

My code is written below.
If anybody can help to fix this issue. I am also adding tracebook here to show error.

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\mas\Desktop\Book1.xlsx')
```

```
        ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-f35cb9e50407> in <module>
----> 1 df= pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\mas\Desktop\Book1.xlsx')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    297                 )
    298                 warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)
--> 299             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    300 
    301         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, storage_options)
    334     if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
    335         should_close = True
--> 336         io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
    337     elif engine and engine != io.engine:
    338         raise ValueError(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in __init__(self, path_or_buffer, engine, storage_options)
   1129         self.storage_options = storage_options
   1130 
-> 1131         self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
   1132 
   1133     def __fspath__(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer, storage_options)
    473         """
    474         import_optional_dependency("openpyxl")
--> 475         super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)
    476 
    477     @property

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer, storage_options)
    389             # N.B. xlrd.Book has a read attribute too
    390             self.handles.handle.seek(0)
--> 391             self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
    392         elif isinstance(self.handles.handle, bytes):
    393             self.book = self.load_workbook(BytesIO(self.handles.handle))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py in load_workbook(self, filepath_or_buffer)
    484         from openpyxl import load_workbook
    485 
--> 486         return load_workbook(
    487             filepath_or_buffer, read_only=True, data_only=True, keep_links=False
    488         )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in load_workbook(filename, read_only, keep_vba, data_only, keep_links)
    315     reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
    316                         data_only, keep_links)
--> 317     reader.read()
    318     return reader.wb

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in read(self)
    279         self.read_properties()
    280         self.read_theme()
--> 281         apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
    282         self.read_worksheets()
    283         self.parser.assign_names()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py in apply_stylesheet(archive, wb)
    196 
    197     node = fromstring(src)
--> 198     stylesheet = Stylesheet.from_tree(node)
    199 
    200     wb._borders = IndexedList(stylesheet.borders)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py in from_tree(cls, node)
    101         for k in attrs:
    102             del node.attrib[k]
--> 103         return super(Stylesheet, cls).from_tree(node)
    104 
    105 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py in from_tree(cls, node)
     81             if hasattr(desc, 'from_tree'):
     82                 #descriptor manages conversion
---> 83                 obj = desc.from_tree(el)
     84             else:
     85                 if hasattr(desc.expected_type, "from_tree"):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py in from_tree(self, node)
     83 
     84     def from_tree(self, node):
---> 85         return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]
     86 
     87 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     83 
     84     def from_tree(self, node):
---> 85         return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]
     86 
     87 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py in from_tree(cls, node)
     85                 if hasattr(desc.expected_type, "from_tree"):
     86                     #complex type
---> 87                     obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
     88                 else:
     89                     #primitive

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py in from_tree(cls, node)
    101                 attrib[tag] = obj
    102 
--> 103         return cls(**attrib)
    104 
    105 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\alignment.py in __init__(self, horizontal, vertical, textRotation, wrapText, shrinkToFit, indent, relativeIndent, justifyLastLine, readingOrder, text_rotation, wrap_text, shrink_to_fit, mergeCell)
     50         self.vertical = vertical
     51         self.indent = indent
---> 52         self.relativeIndent = relativeIndent
     53         self.justifyLastLine = justifyLastLine
     54         self.readingOrder = readingOrder

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py in __set__(self, instance, value)
    105             value = _convert(self.expected_type, value)
    106             if value < self.min:
--> 107                 raise ValueError('Min value is {0}'.format(self.min))
    108         super(Min, self).__set__(instance, value)
    109 

ValueError: Min value is 0
```

Comment: Since we can't check the excel contents, have you tried checking the [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) documentation? Seems like you are missing an argument that is causing the function to do something wrong based on default values.

Comment: The full traceback would be helpful.

Comment: did you compare your openpyxl module versions?

Answer (score -2):

You have to remove r in 2 line.

import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('C:\Users\mas\Desktop\Book1.xlsx')

I hope it will work.